# How should i structure a node js and mongodb project

Tags: android, node.js, mongodb, api, ionic-framework

I want to build an event app,that has a normal web app that shows events  and also an admin panel for the site administrator and another admin panel for a regular event planner where they can see analytics on their events.It also has an ionic pwa for the end users and an Android app/Ios app for the bouncers or gatehuys that has the list of attendees for each event

I haven’t done something of this scale before and i need advice on how to structure the whole thing

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the web app framework chosen, I’d look for the most commonly used/popular boilerplate project/scaffold and use its project structure as a starting point. I found that the number of stars on github is a good indicator of popularity. Even better, find a officially supported scaffolding tool; ie express-generator